# Using btrfs with bcache on /

Tags: boot, btrfs, bcache

I am using btrfs with bcache for / on Ubuntu 13.10. It's fast. Unfortunately, during normal boots the step "Scanning for btrfs filesystems" fails. To successfully boot I have to enter recovery mode and then simply choose the menu option "continue to the main system".

I assume a normal boot fails because the bcache0 device has not finished being created by the time btrfs scans for its filesystems. How can I insert a delay between these steps?

Answer (score 1):

Btrfs is actually supposed to react to new devices dynamically, through udev calling `btrfs device ready`/`BTRFS_IOC_DEVICE_READY`. See `/lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules`. This logic obsoletes `btrfs device scan` which is inappropriate for a dynamic boot. According to [this](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2013-July/012043.html), Btrfs' messages to udev have a flag to tell when there's enough backing devices to mount the Btrfs filesystem on them.

However, I'm not sure that mountall (an underdocumented piece of software that scans `/etc/fstab` and calls mount) implements the rest. The solution involves either fixing mountall or hacking up something that could be specific to your system, putting the mount command in `/etc/rc.local` or a custom udev rule.

Comment: I don't actually have to do anything in recovery mode however. I just choose the first option "continue". I don't know whether it runs "mountall" as a side-effect.

Comment: It probably works because the recovery boot delays mountall. That's another possible workaround; add a `sleep 1` to `/etc/init/mountall.conf`. Apparently you can also add a `--debug` in there.

Comment: There is also a "rootdelay=3" [seconds] kernel boot option that some people recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Btrfs is not currently stable with bcache (Feb 2014) - this is a known bug and being worked on, but for the moment I'd strongly advise against this use.

Comment: Yes, it was fast, but I got tired of reformatting. On the plus side the newly-created btrfs filesystem seems to work better in general than the years-old one.